# replace space with plus sign but remove end space

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm not very familiar with `regex` things, and came up to replace any space with `+` sign but if string has some space at end.. I want to remove them. so this is my try:

```js
let str = "blah blah blah   ";
let res = str.replace(/\s+/g, '+');
console.log(res);
```

but the result I have looking for is:

> blah+blah+blah

but this little code give me this:

> blah+blah+blah+

Comment: If this is any more complex, _trim_ won't work (see the answer). Generally for more complex exclusions and trimming, a regex callback is needed to intervene the logic, on a case by case basis, that which should be replaced and by what. This method is a one stop shopping way that encompasses all more complicated replacements. Even if it were shown how to do this most only want the apparent quick fix. Nobody learns..

Comment: You can match all words and then join them up with `+`: `str.match(/\S+/g).join('+')`

Answer (score 3):

You need to trim your string first (removing spaces at the begining and the end of the string)

```
let str = "blah blah blah   ";
let res = str.trim().replace(/\s+/g, '+');
console.log(res);
```